# How load data from mySQL to JSON in EXTJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, extjs

I create file in my store folder, i want load my data from mySQL to JSon, so this is my code:

```
Ext.define('DWP3.store.konten.Coba', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
alias: 'store.coba',
uses: [
    'Ext.data.Store'
],

initComponent: function(){

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: [
           {name: 'periode'},
           {name: 'Teknik Informatika S1'},
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'resources/data/load2.php',
            reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'view_aktif'
            }
        },
         autoLoad: true
    });

}
   });
```

how can i load the data from store?
Can You Help me Please.

Comment: i try load this data become a chart..but this data cannot called

Comment: There is no `initComponent` method in [`Ext.data.Store`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Store). Even if there was one, why would you create one store inside another?

Comment: oke thank you your help...i understood now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems better to me declared this way :

```
Ext.define('DWP3.store.konten.Coba', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        alias: 'store.coba',
        fields: [
                   {name: 'periode'},
                   {name: 'Teknik Informatika S1'},
        ],
        proxy: {
               type: 'ajax',
               url : 'resources/data/load2.php',
               reader: {
               type: 'json',
               rootProperty: 'view_aktif'
       },
       autoLoad: true
});
```